# Relative amplitude of the exceptional divisor

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, divisors

Let $f:X'\to X$ be a projective birational morphism between complete algebraic varieties. Assume that the exceptional locus ${\rm Exc}(f)$ is the support of an effective Cartier divisor, can we choose this divisor to be $f$-anti-ample?

When $X$ is regular, $f$ is isomorphic to a blowup along a subscheme $Z$ such that ${\rm Exc}(f)=f^{-1}(Z)$ (GTM 52, II, E.x. 7.11(c)). As a consequence, the answer to the question above is affirmative when $X$ is regular.

See [Projectivity of blowups](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/71264/projectivity-of-blowups) for a similar question and an affirmative answer when $X$ has only $\mathbb{Q}$-factorial singularities.

Comment: In the second paragraph, to use Hartshorne, you need to assume $X$ is regular instead of $X’$?

Comment: @Chen Jiang Thank you for the comment, I have fixed the error.